# ThreeJS - How to output canvas into specific div?

Tags: canvas, three.js

It seems that the canvas is simply inserted into the body, at the bottom of the flow. I was wondering which bit of code do I need to change to get it to insert into a specific div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is usually this line:

```
container = document.createElement( 'div' );

//later in that file
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

change the first line to:

```
container = document.getElementById( 'mycustomdiv' );
```

Comment: You're right, but i fixed it by just adding this to the bottom of body:

$("canvas").appendTo("#canvascontainer");

Comment: Just be aware that if you'll have another canvas the JQuery 'canvas' will find all the canvas elements.

Answer (score 3):

You could create the canvas yourself and put it to your desired location. Then pass it to the renderer constructor like this: `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: myCanvasElem });` See the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer).